# How use next $.each() value in previous $.each() as value object

Tags: jquery

My code is as follows

```
$.each(arr, function (index, value) {
     
   var row = $('.marksEntryForm').find('table tbody').find('tr.std_adm_' + value.adm_no);
     
   $.each(data.distributions, function (i, dval) {           
           
     // row.find("td input."+dval).val(value.dval);
           
   });
});
```

```
row.find("td input.theory").val(value.theory);
row.find("td input.practical").val(value.practical);
```

need to write many lines with replacing value.xxxx

like theory , practical and etc. i am fetching in second $.each() as dval.
i m trying to replacing all obects with value.dval not like value.theory, value.practical etc..

how to do it

Comment: What's wrong with `row.find("td input."+dval).val(value.dval);`? can you explain more? like what is the error?

Comment: Without your html and what data and arr contains, it hard to give you a good answer. but look at this https://jsfiddle.net/s265gfet/

Answer (score 0):

```
$.each(arr, function (index, value) {
     
   var row = $('.marksEntryForm').find('table tbody').find('tr.std_adm_' + value.adm_no);
     
   $.each(data.distributions, function (i, dval) {           
           
     row.find("td input."+dval).val(value[dval]);
           
   });
});
```

Comment: Need to replace val(value.dval) with val(value[dval])

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context (within the answer) regarding why and/or how this code answers the question improves its long-term value.